# determining phase constants in SHM

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator

A particle moves along the x axis. It is initially at the position $x$ of $0.300 m$, moving with velocity $v$ of $0.070 m/s$ and acceleration $a$ of  $-0.330 m/s^2$. Suppose it moves with constant acceleration for $5.60 s$.

amplitude $A=0.30733$

$\omega= 1.049$

Find its phase constant phi if cosine is used for the equation of motion. Hint: when taking the inverse of a trig function, there are always two angles but your calculator will tell you only one and you must decide which of the two angles you need.

**Attempt:**

$$x(t)= Acos(\omega t-\phi)$$

we know at time $t=0$ the displacement of the particle is $.3$ 
we also know the acceleration is negative and the velocity is positive meaning it is currently on its way to reach the maximum displacement.

so at

- $t=0$
- $x(0)=.3$
- $\omega$ is known
- $A$ is known

$$.3=.30733 \: cos(1.049(0) - \phi)$$

$\phi = -12.5$

and it's wrong

**things were i think i might possibly gone wrong:**

- the assumption that $-\phi$ is inside the parentheses. I said this was the case because displacement has to increase until the amplitude is reached because velocity is positive so the cosine curve would have to be shifted to the right.
- something weird going on with the inverse trig function that i am not taking into account like the hint suggests.

Comment: The $\phi$ should be within the parenteses, it is a phase difference, and it moves the graph sideways. If you would move it out of the $\cos$ it would an added factor to the function, moving if downwards. See http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=compare+cos%28x%29+and+cos%28x-1%29+ and http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=compare+cos%28x%29+and+cos%28x%29-1+

Comment: that is what i did (and i believe what i wrote on the site) i put the ϕ within the parentheses. so i divided .3 by .30700. then took the inverse of cos and then divided by -1 to solve for ϕ and got -12.5

Answer (score 1):

We know that:

\begin{align}
x(t) &= A \cos(\omega t - \phi), && x(0)= A\cos(-\phi)=0.3,\\
\dot x(t)&=-A\omega\sin(\omega t - \phi), && \dot x(0)=-A\omega\sin(-\phi)= 0.07,\\
\ddot x(t)&=-A\omega^2\cos(\omega t - \phi), && \ddot x(0)=-A\omega^2\cos(-\phi)=-0.33.
\end{align}

We know that $\phi=12.5º$ or $\phi=-12.5º$, lets find out which one it is. You said that the particle is on its way  to reach the maximum displacement. This occurs when $\cos(\omega t-\phi)=1\Rightarrow \omega t -\phi =90º.$ Also, the velocity at $t=0$ tells us that $\sin(-\phi)<0\Rightarrow \phi >0$. Therefore the angle is positive and is in the first quadrant. Therefore it would be $12.5º$.